# XBL Orbeon custom control to show different success message on form save

Tags: xml, forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud, xbl

I am using yForm (Orbeon Form Builder) to generate form run time, where we have a requirement to set different custom success message for each form (eg: "Your contact form save successfully", "Your address form…"). I would like to configure this success message from Form Builder, so that whenever an end user saves that form, it can see the corresponding custom message.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that by "success message", you are referring to the message shown next to the buttons that are at the bottom of the form.

This message is shown when the [`success-message()` action](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#success-message-and-error-message) runs. Actions are executed by a processes, which, at the time of this writing, can't defined in Form Builder, but are instead defined in your `properties-local.xml`. If you are new to this, I'd recommend you have a look at the [Buttons and processes](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/) section of the documentation.

Comment: Yes I am new to this, Can you please suggest the strategy using which we can configure different success message for each form while creating form through builder(Also admin can change it later). I am not able to understand the flow through this document. It would great if you have any reference which explain the whole flow with example.

Comment: @U2Answer, I'd recommend you start reading the documentation on Buttons and processes linked above. It's one of the most involved part of the product, so book a few hours for this ;). Then try creating your own button which when pressed just shows a success message by calling `success-message(message = "{'Hello, world!'}")`. I think that will give you a good understanding of buttons and processes. (Then you can change the static `'Hello, world!'` to an XPath expression which points to the value of a hidden field defined by the form author in Form Builder.)

Comment: Thanks!! I already have done static message change. But I was confused how to assign dynamic value to that. also how to make filed as hidden(custom control)

Comment: Can you please let me know any example for `XPath expression which points to the value of a hidden field defined by the form author in Form Builder`

Comment: @U2Answer Say you have a field named `my-field` in a section named `my-section`, you can then access its value from XPath with `/form/my-section/my-field`. So if you want to show the value of that field in a success message, you'd write `success-message(message = "{/form/my-section/my-field}")`.

Comment: Thanks!! 
is that mandatory to give form and section name here, as form is generated dynamic so it could be anything. So is there any generic way ?

Comment: @U2Answer `/form` is always just that, for all your forms. I.e. the root element of the XML document that contains the data users enter in the form is always `<form>`, irrelevant of the app name and form name. And the section name is whatever forms authors use. You'll need to have a convention there: for instance "telling" form authors to name the section `private` and the field `success-message`. Then in your process you'll use `/form/private/success-message`, and this will work for all the forms.

Comment: With your help I have some work around to show custom message, I will post the code over here!!. But problem here is, the message will persist with each form data. I have posted the question for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/39318179/2478134

Comment: @U2Answer Correct, with the technique described here, the message is stored with the data, which I agree is a bit weird, but in some (maybe even most?) cases won't be a problem either.

Comment: Yes it won't be a problem if value is static. But in my case if admin change the value then it won't affect the existing form(form edit), as those forms already saved with old value. It will work only with new form data!! Please help.

Comment: @U2Answer Understood. So, [adding the success to the metadata instance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39356212/5295) might be a better solution in that case.