# Orbeon Custom metadata at form level

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder, xbl

I want to configure *success message*(`successMessageTextBox`) and *downloadLink*(`linkTextbox`) at form level(meta-data) through `formBuilder`, so that admin can change and publish it anytime. Also these values can be accessible to `properties-local.xml` file to configure the `success-message`.

e.g:

```
navigate(uri="{xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')//linkTextbox}")

success-message(message = "{xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')//successMessageTextBox}")
```

**Any suggestion would be appreciated!!**

***UPDATE*** :-

1>MetaData

```
  if (exists(xxf:instance('fr-form-metadata')/linkTextbox)‌​) 
            then navigate(uri="{xxf:instance('fr-form-metadata')/linkTextbox}")
            else nop
```

2>Formfeild

```
if (exists(xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//linkTextbox)‌​) 
        then success-message(message = "{xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//linkTextbox}") 
        else then success-message("save-success")
```

**Code snap exists**

```
 <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*">
            require-uploads
            then validate-all
            then save
            if (exists(xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//linkTextbox)‌​) 
            then navigate(uri="{xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//linkTextbox}")
            else nop
            recover error-message("database-error") 
  </property>
```

**Code snap is-blank**

```
    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*">
                    require-uploads
                    then validate-all
                    then save
                   then
                   (
                     if ("not(xxf:is-blank(xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//msg))") 
                     then success-message(message = "{xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//msg}")
                     else nop
                    )
                    recover error-message("database-error") 
          </property>
```

**Error log** :-

```
2016-09-26 23:06:44,925 INFO  lifecycle  - event: {"request": "21", "session": "AA57957F553E16581E264D06E3241BFD", "source": "fr", "message": "start: process", "uuid": "3bd78eb64e035d7d710a74049c972aca086b095a", "scope": "oxf.fr.detail.process", "name": "save-final-custom"}
2016-09-26 23:06:45,302 ERROR XFormsServer  - 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Invalid source:                                                                                                       |
|Invalid input 'f', expected OptWhiteSpace or ')' (line 9, pos 39):                                                    |
|  if ('not(xxf:is-blank(xxf:instanc                                                                                   |
|e('fr-form-instance')//msg))')                                                                                        |
|                                      ^                                                                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.parboiled.errors.ParsingException                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.ProcessParser$           |parse                         |ProcessParser.scala           | 121|
|nterpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$parseProcess$1$1|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 201|
|nterpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$parseProcess$1$1|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 201|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$BooleanWrapper$     |option$extension              |ScalaUtils.scala              | 115|
|n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|parseProcess$1                |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 201|
|n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|runSubProcess                 |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 203|
|nonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 235|
|nonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 235|
|scala.util.control.Breaks$$anon$1                  |catchBreak                    |Breaks.scala                  |  63|
|un$runProcess$3$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 236|
|un$runProcess$3$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 233|
|scala.util.Success                                 |flatMap                       |Try.scala                     | 231|
|Interpreter$$anonfun$runProcess$3$$anonfun$apply$11|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 233|
|Interpreter$$anonfun$runProcess$3$$anonfun$apply$11|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 241|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.DynamicVariable                |withValue                     |DynamicVariable.scala         |  42|
|n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|withEmptyStack                |ProcessInterpreter.scala      |  96|
|fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$$anonfun$runProcess$3|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 232|
|fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$$anonfun$runProcess$3|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 232|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2016-09-26 23:06:45,396 INFO  lifecycle  - event: {"request": "21", "session": "AA57957F553E16581E264D06E3241BFD", "source": "fr", "message": "end: process", "time": "471 ms"}
2016-09-26 23:06:45,593 INFO  lifecycle  - event: {"request": "21", "session": "AA57957F553E16581E264D06E3241BFD", "source": "xforms", "message": "after cacheOrStore", "document cache current size": "1", "document cache max size": "50"}
2016-09-26 23:06:45,594 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 1198
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather add this to the `fr-form-metadata` instance, e.g. by editing the source of the form in Form Builder, and adding, say, a `<success-message>` inside `<metadata>`:

```
<xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <metadata>
        ...
        <success-message>Submitted, all good!</success-message>
    </metadata>
</xf:instance>
```

Then, in your process, you can show that message with:

```
success-message(message = "{xxf:instance('fr-form-metadata')/success-message}")
```

Comment: I have tried this option, user can see configured custom message, but still facing the same issue, If I have changed the messaged and publish it again, old user can't see updated message.

Comment: Which database are you using? If a relational database, when publishing, did you choose to update the existing version of the form? If you created a new version, then indeed the message won't change, as the version of the form definition that was used to create the form is also used when editing it, which is the point of versioning.

Comment: OK, out of the box, Orbeon Forms uses eXist, on which there is no versioning, so when you republish the form with the new message, the old version will be overwritten, and the new message will be taken into account next time you edit data using that form. Are you sure you republished the form after changing the message?

Comment: Thanks!! my mistake, I was not refreshing page. once I have refreshed the page then save the data, its working.

Comment: if `linkTextbox` value not found in the process then it break the functionality, So can I have some condition to skip navigate if no value found.

Comment: @U2Answer Excellent, I am glad it worked after refreshing the page. And yes, you can have conditionals in processes: see [conditions](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/syntax.html#conditions) in the processes syntax. I.e. `if (exists(xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')//linkTextbox)) then navigate(…) else nop`.

Comment: I have tried it, but it's not working. Please find my updated post

Comment: @U2Answer Are you getting an error? How is it not working? Is it taking the "wrong" branch of the `if` statement? I am not sure what you mean by "it is going inside `recover error-message("database-error")`"; the snippet you show for your process doesn't have this `recover…`. Maybe it would help if you could put the whole source of your process.

Comment: I have put the snap shot, This is my understanding for that code snap "when anything break then it might go in `recover` which prompt `connection error to end user`".

Comment: @U2Answer OK, thank you for sharing the source. 3 things: 1. I think you need a `then` before that `if`. 2. I'd also recommend you put parenthesis around the `if`, for clarity. 3. You need quotes around the XPath expression inside the `if(…)`. See [how I think it should look like](https://gist.github.com/avernet/5b6654ef2c2428a3010248a83fec8ad6). If it still doesn't work, can you reproduce the problem, and just after that copy the content of your `orbeon.log` into a Gist?

Comment: Look like it is working if filed it self is not define. But if field is there with no value(blank), then its fail!!(`exists function might return true in this case`). Is there any function which tack care of both `NULL & BLANK` value ?

Comment: @U2Answer If you want to test whether an *existing* element content is empty, you can use `xxf:is-blank()`. In your case, you'd have `if (exists(xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')//linkTextbox)‌ and not(xxf:is-blank(xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')//linkTextbox)))`, which can be simplified as `if (not(xxf:is-blank(xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')//linkTextbox)))`, since `xxf:is-blank()` returns true if it receives an empty sequence.

Comment: I have tested it, but it is not working. Please find updated code snap!!

Comment: @U2Answer You are missing single quotes inside the `if()`. It needs to be `if('XPath expression')`. Also, if it doesn't work, check the `orbeon.log`: you'll typically see an exception there that should help you find what the problem is.

Comment: @U2Answer I see: since the expression is in a string, it takes the first `'` character inside the XPath expression as being the end of the expression. Try using double quotes, i.e. instead of `if('XPath expression')`, try `if("XPath expression")`, and inside the XPath expression keep single quotes.

Comment: @U2Answer Woo-hoo! And congratulations for being so persistent on this one. It will get easier as XPath and other techs become more familiar to you.

Comment: Sure will learn `XPath` and other techs. which involved in Orbeon